# Label text not showing after postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, telerik

Label text not showing when im click button event. Because telerik control using in this page. 
How to solve this issue?

I mention the example coding in following below

**ASP.NET Code**

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
</telerik:RadWindowManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Skin="Default" Text="Register Client"
 OnClientClicked="CreateTPA">  </telerik:RadButton>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<div><asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></div>
```

VB.NET Code

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

lblmsg.Text = "Error!"
```

End Sub

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lblmsg.Text` instead of `ltrlMsg.Text`?

Comment: Sorry, that is spell mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pullout the button 'btnSave' to outside update panel and check

Answer (score 0):

The label `ltrlMsg` is not inside of the `UpdatePanel` of the button. Where is it?

Presuming that it's in another `UpdatePanel` you could add an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="ltrlMsg" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Edit**: Now that you've edited your question this doesn't seem to be helpful, is it?

Comment: Already i'm working telerik red button control    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Skin="Default" Text="Register Client"
 OnClientClicked="CreateTPA">  </telerik:RadButton>